# static lib call error: Exception: "A null reference pointer was passed to the stub." (using winsock2 Win32)

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-studio-2008, winsock2

I created a windows-console application that works fine but trying to use Winsock2 (Ws2_32.lib) in another static-library (as part of a larger project) throws an exception.

The code compiles fine and the exe runs all is well, calls to WSAStartup() and gethostbyname() work as expected but then calling gethostbyname()
causes :

`First-chance exception at 0x76e1c41f in TestApp.exe: 0x000006F4: A null reference pointer was passed to the stub.`

which leads to:

`First-chance exception at 0x7505cd99 (rpcrt4.dll) in TestApp.exe: 0xC0020043: An internal error occurred in RPC.`

Ive double checked the calling code is the same and checked that the correct versions of the *.h *.dll and *.lib are being used by the linker - as far as i can tell they are.
I've compared the project settings for the two apps and cant see anything out of the ordinary. 
Ive also made sure that all the libraries in the Project are using the same Character-Set.

[EDIT : chages after discovering the difference in the two apps is just the debugger exceptions being turned on or not ]

I can continue past the exceptions and the code appears to run, but I no longer have valid debugging symbols in the function. It isnt a crash but of course id rather not have the exceptions every time I call the function - I can obviously turn the exception-breaks off but aren't they there to tell me something is wrong ?

I am currently trying to get the up-to-date symbols for the ws2_32.lib and other modules from the MSDN symbol server / SymChk.exe

[EDIT 2 - finally got symbols for the stack]

```
>   rpcrt4.dll!_NdrClientCall2()  + 0x301 bytes 
    FWPUCLNT.DLL!_FwppProxyEngineOpen@24()  + 0x19 bytes    
    FWPUCLNT.DLL!_FwppSessionCreate@20()  + 0xd1 bytes  
    FWPUCLNT.DLL!_FwpmEngineOpen0@20()  + 0x29 bytes    
    FWPUCLNT.DLL!_FwpIsNameCacheEnabledForProcess@4()  + 0x7778 bytes   
    FWPUCLNT.DLL!_FwpmProcessNameResolutionEvent0@16()  + 0x74 bytes    
    FWPUCLNT.DLL!_NamespaceCallout@12()  + 0x72 bytes   
    ws2_32.dll!PrepareNamespaceCalloutBlob()  + 0x153 bytes 
    ws2_32.dll!getxyDataEnt()  + 0x74a7 bytes   
    ws2_32.dll!_gethostbyname@4()  + 0xe7 bytes
```

Comment: Run it in a debugger and look closely at the [stack-trace/backtrace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_trace)

Comment: Unfortunatly I can't find the symbols for ws2_32.lib and the stack only provides :

Comment: [commenting time ran out :\ ] (@Huytard) the stack : `KernelBase.dll!75f1c41f()`  
  `[Frames below may be incorrect and/or missing, no symbols loaded for KernelBase.dll]` 
  `KernelBase.dll!75f1c41f()`  
  `rpcrt4.dll!LRPC_BASE_CCALL::FreeObject()  + 0x3c38 bytes` 
`> rpcrt4.dll!_RpcpRaiseException@4()  + 0x2f bytes` which corresponds to the asm `75F1C419  call        dword ptr ds:[75F1115Ch]` 
`75F1C41F  leave`

Answer (score 1):

I was getting this exception `"0x000006F4: A null reference pointer was passed to the stub."`

Turns out disabling my 3rd party firewall stopped the exception being thrown. Perhaps the firewall is intercepting the request and messing something up.

Might be worth a try for you :)